# Why is driver.getPlaform() returning ANY for MicrosoftWebDriver for Edge in Windows 10?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

```
DesiredCapabilities edge = new DesiredCapabilities(Browser.EDGE, "", Platform.Windows);
RemoteWebDriver driver = RemoteWebDriver(remoteAddress,edge);
System.out.println(driver.getCapabilities().getPlatform());
```

This prints the platform as ANY, even though I set the platform as Platform.Windows. I am using Windows 10 with the latest MicrosoftWebDriver.exe(10.0.14393). How can I get the platform as Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform returned in the session is coming from the browser driver executable. It may not be exactly what you passed in. If the browser driver executable (`MicrosoftWebDriver.exe` in the case of Microsoft Edge) is returning `ANY` (or nothing) in its response for a new session, that's what is being returned to your code. Microsoft would need to make the change in their driver to change this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to know if the web driver is running in a Windows 10 desktop environment?

Comment: Considering that at the time of this writing, Microsoft Edge **only** runs on Windows 10, excluding server operating systems, I'd say the answer is yes.